# Phaser hide certain tiles

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a roguelike game using javascript and Phaser. To handle the map I am using Phaser's TileMap.
I have a working Line of Sight algorithm that computes which tiles are visible, but I don't know how to actually hide the other tiles.
Since Tile objects don't have a "visible" attribute, I tried to set the alpha attribute to 0. This works, but leads to performance issues.

How can I efficiently hide tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Create another tilemap layer with tiles that cover tiles with "blank" tiles; blank tiles as in the surrounding tiles to blend in.

```
_ __   __  _ _  //layer 1 lo dashes represent "blank" tiles
^-^^---^^--^-^- //layer 2 "^" representing whatever you want to hide.
```

"_" and "-" representing the same tile image